# Convert jpg images to webp

Tags: wordpress, webp

I'm trying to convert .jpg images to webp format.

I have site in WordPress, and I need to add webp to my images. I read https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/ but it does not work for me.

And I tried using https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-webp/ but that also does not work.

And I tried this article, also doesn't work http://www.wpexplorer.com/webp-files-wordpress/

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code examples?

Comment: i use above plugin

Comment: people will need a better definition of your problem than "not working".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your question. You are showing what you've tried, that's great! However, the only thing you tell us about the result is "does not work". That's not telling us much. You could further improve your question by editing it yourself. Explain the techniques in these articles, so the question does not rely on the links. And then explain _how_ these techniques failed - what happened when you tried them.

Comment: If your question tells us in more detail what you've tried - then it is also more likely that search engines will pick up your question. In this way, people with the right knowledge have a better chance of finding your question.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

apt get install moreutils

apt get install parallels

parallel -eta cwebp {} -o {.}.webp ::: *.jpg

works with *.png too 100000 images at the time if you want

One image at the time can be done with cwebp -q 100 image1.jpg -o image1.webp

Sorry got this from another thread but he missed a dot before webp

Answer (score 0):

To convert images from WebP format into JPG and PNG format you can use WebPconv 6.0 (Windows only).

It's a free app and you can find it [here](http://www.romeolight.com/products/webpconv/).